# read dynamic number of images of same shape into Python NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, glob

I have this code:

```
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Utilizador\\Desktop\\menu\\*.jpg'): 
    im=cv2.imread(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
```

This creates me a list of images, but I need it to be in an array form with shape (num_of_images, width, height, 3)

All images have the same shape
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: yes they have the same shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all images have same shape, we can create an empty array and then read each image into that.

```
In [103]: file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Utilizador\\Desktop\\menu\\*.jpg'
In [104]: num_imgs = len(glob.glob(file_path))
In [105]: width, height, channels = 512, 512, 3

In [106]: batch_arr = np.empty((num_imgs, width, height, channels), dtype=np.uint8)

In [107]: for idx, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(file_path)):
              img = cv2.imread(filename)
              # if img is of different width and height than defined above
              # do some resize and then insert in the array.
              batch_arr[idx] = img
```

Comment: That works, but I would like something more dynamic, where the number of images, width, height would not be fixed, like a way to read the images and just append them as an array instead of a list

Comment: But will it be possible to then edit the images, like resizing them for example inside the array? Or should I do it before I add them to the array?

Comment: there is an issue, the original image is uint8 format and when I append to the array, it becames float64 and this messes up the image.